# How to scale services with optional / additional parameters docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: 3.7
services:
   sensor:
      image: vs-power-system:latest
      environment: 
         COMPONENTNAME: $COMPONENTNAME
```

(I wrote the image myself, I can provide it if needed)

I have to start this service a couple of times, so I use

`COMPONENTNAME=Consumer docker-compose up --scale sensor=5`

The image executes something like this:

`java -jar /app/someProgram.jar $COMPONENTNAME`

A sensor in this context can either be a consumer or a producer. If it should be a producer, another variable, a capacity, has to be passed in.

My question is: Is there a way to scale this service for example 5 times in a way, where I can add another parameter for the 5th instance?

I found something similar on [the docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/pass-incremental-variable-to-cmd-for-each-scaled-service-in-docker-compose/16371), but there was no answer.
I also read somewhere, that `docker-compose` does not support such a behaviour and that `docker swarm` could be used. However, I have to use `docker-compose` for this task.

If it is not possible in the described way, could I change my `docker-compose.yml` to the following:

```yaml
version: 3.7
services:
   consumer:
      image: vs-power-system:latest
      environment: 
         COMPONENTNAME: $COMPONENTNAME
   producer: 
      image: vs-power-system:latest
      environment:
         COMPONENTNAME: $COMPONENTNAME
         CAPACITY: $CAPACITY
```

And scale the `consumer` service for example 4 times with one parameter and after that scale the `producer` service for example 3 times with 2 parameters?

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of image files to this question, but Compose usually runs off of text-format YAML files.  Can you replace the images with the actual text of the files you're using and not screen shots of your IDE?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the `scale` configuration is how many instances to run of your service. In your case, you want to run 4 instances of the consumer service and 1 instance of the producer service. It doesn't matter if the image is the same - it's still a different service as its configuration changes (in your case a simple environment variable).

Also, `docker-compose` in general isn't "scriptable".

The best practice would be to split it to a different configuration just like the solution you suggested.
Another benefit of this approach is that it allows you to dynamically scale the producers independently of the consumers.